# Network equipment in low temperatures

Tags: switch

I need a switch that will connect all of the ethernet cables that run through my house. Unfortunately all of this cable came out in a box which is situated outside the house. The box is somehow sealed but not insulated. Can a normal network switch work there (there working temperature is most of the time between 0-40C) or do i need to use one of the industrial ones which have a much brother working temperature range. I am mostly worried about negative temperatures in winter (it can go as low as -20C in my area) and with condensation.

Comment: Hi Andrei, please note this question is not within the scope of the network engineering stack exchange. Here we focus on enterprise grade equipment. To answer your question, I would suggest you not put the switch outside. You can pick up a cheap, 4-port or 8-port switch (depending on your needs) to connect your entire household.

Comment: The bigger issue here is not absolute temp, but the daily variation in temp. Your network box needs to be in a better controlled space. (I certainly wouldn't pay any electrician that installs something that bad)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

All the equipment have its own environment requirements and you can learn them from documentation. Usual equipment have 0-40C range, but it definitely will work in lower temperatures with following restrictions:

1. Lower temperature values are not guaranteed to work. Capacitors and CPUs can vitally change behavior in -20C.
2. Switch will heat the box and temperature inside will be higher depending on how it is sealed.
3. You can place a small heater inside and ensure that water can't directly pass into the box.

Your most problem is not the equipment, but connectors. Standard RJ-45 connector will stop working after two nights of temperature crossing 0C.

Conclusion: There are no certain characteristics, but more dry and warm inside - more surviving it will be. You can use any equipment you can find. Being dry is on first place, warm on second.

Comment: Without insulation, the temp inside the box will not be substantially higher than outside.